# View size when subclassing PFLogInViewController

Tags: ios7, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

When subclassing PFLogInViewController for customization. How do I change the size of the view?
I have looked at this tutorial: https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views
but it does not seem to have the answer.

My app is based on a UITabBarController and one of the tabs needs log in.
Nevertheless if the user cannot log in, he should still be able to use the other tabs.

In the present situation, when the user taps on the tab asking for login; he has to log in or kill the app to get out. Because the PFLogInViewController takes up all the screen and there is no way out by hitting a different tab (all covered).
This is obviously not very nice.
How can I keep the tabs at the bottom visible?

I tried to change the self.view.frame or the self.logInView.frame in the viewDidLoad method of my PFLogInViewController subclass, but it seems to have no effect at all.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should make your app so that it doesn't start with the login viewcontroller, but rather opens to the parts that are available to all. Include some button or other mechanic to take the user to the login page.

You could include a button on the login page that says "Use the app anonymously" or similar, which triggers a segue to a main view. On subsequent app launches, the user is taken to this main view immediately. You would still need a way for the user to login later on.

Comment: Obviously you are right and that is what I do. The app does not start with the login viewcontroller. The problem appears if the user happens to go to the tab asking for login. There is already a way for the user to log in if he wants to (precisely the tab I am referring to). As you mention I may be able to put a button to get out of the login screen, but it would just be so much simpler if I could have this login screen not cover the UITabBar at the bottom of the screen. Then the tabs would be available for the user to go to another tab where login is not needed. And it must be possible.